# Can i change the default AWS EC2 Public DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, icmp, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm using **Route 53** and created **A record** to the **Elastic IP** that associated with an instance.

In Security Group, i activated the **"All ICMP"** and make it accessible from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) so i can ping it.

When i pinged my domain this is the output:

```
64 bytes from ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_req=477 ttl=55 time=19.5 ms
```

**Question:**

Can i change the public DNS so the output will be like below?

```
64 bytes from my.domain.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx): icmp_req=477 ttl=55 time=19.5 ms
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set up a reverse DNS as well. This is a PTR record in the `.in-addr.arpa` zone that points an IP address to a FQDN. Typically, the owner of the IP subnet that you're leasing your address from provides you with a way to add reverse DNS entries, as whoever owns the subnet also controls the relevant `.in-addr.arpa` zone.

From reading [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/234815/how-to-add-a-reverse-ptr-record-on-amazon-route-53), it looks like that Amazon haven't got the ability to add reverse DNS records within Route 53. However, the answers in that question do mention that if you have an elastic IP allocated, you can submit a reverse DNS request over at https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request.